# Admitting d'Alembert's formula with the solution

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> How can I prove
>
> $$
> u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}(\varphi(x+t)+\varphi(x-t))+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\psi(y)dy
> $$ satisfies the following Cauchy problem:
>
> $$\begin{cases}
> \partial_{t}^{2}u-\partial_{x}^{2}u=0\\
> u(0,x)=\varphi(x)\\
> \partial_{t}u(0,x)=\psi(x)
> \end{cases}
> $$

Here are my results (so far):

$$
\begin{split}
\partial_{t}u &= \frac{1}{2}\varphi_{t}^{,}(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\varphi_{t}^{,}(x-t)+\frac{1}{2}\psi(x+t)+\frac{1}{2}\psi(x-t)\\
\partial_{t}^{2}u &= \frac{1}{2}\varphi_{tt}^{,,}(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\varphi_{tt}^{,,}(x-t)+\frac{1}{2}\psi_{t}^{,}(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\psi_{t}^{,}(x-t)\\
\partial_{x}u &= \frac{1}{2}\varphi_{x}^{,}(x+t)+\frac{1}{2}\varphi_{x}^{,}(x-t)+\frac{1}{2}\psi(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\psi(x-t)\\
\partial_{x}^{2}u &= \frac{1}{2}\varphi_{xx}^{,,}(x+t)+\frac{1}{2}\varphi_{xx}^{,,}(x-t)+\frac{1}{2}\psi_{x}^{,}(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\psi_{x}^{,}(x-t)
\end{split}
$$
Substituting into $\partial_{t}^{2}u-\partial_{x}^{2}u=0\\$, I got $\varphi_{tt}^{,,}-\varphi_{xx}^{,,}=0$.

What did I missed?

Substituting $t$ into the derivatives I also got the initial values therefore it must be correct, but how do I know $\varphi_{tt}^{,,}=\varphi_{xx}^{,,}$?

I tried to do something with the operators: $\partial_{t}^{2}-\partial_{x}^{2}=(\partial_{t}-\partial_{x})(\partial_{t}+\partial_{x})$ but it didnt help.

Sorry if the question is obvious but I really can't solve it.

Comment: I'm sad to say that I didn't realize this was a math operator (I only knew it as a Yu-Gi-Oh card. Sheesh). Well, we all learn sometime.

Comment: $\partial_{t}^{2}u = \psi^{'}(x+t) = \partial_x^{2}u$

Comment: What is $\varphi''_{xx}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here are my results (so far):
>
> $$\partial_{t}^{2}u = \frac{1}{2}\varphi_{tt}^{,,}(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\varphi_{tt}^{,,}(x-t)+\frac{1}{2}\psi_{t}^{,}(x+t)-\frac{1}{2}\psi_{t}^{,}(x-t)$$

The $-\frac{1}{2}\varphi_{tt}^{,,}(x-t)$ term should be positive. You forgot to multiply by negative one.

Also, the notation $\varphi_{tt}^{,,}(x-t)$ is slightly confusing as you didn't specify that it means to take two partial derivatives with respect to $t$. It might be best to stick with $\varphi_{tt}$ or $\varphi''$.

We need to show that d'Alembert's formula

$$
u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi(x+t)+\varphi(x-t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\psi(y)dy
$$

satisfies the Cauchy problem

$$\begin{cases}
\partial_{t}^{2}u-\partial_{x}^{2}u=0\\
u(0,x)=\varphi(x)\\
\partial_{t}u(0,x)=\psi(x)
\end{cases}
$$

Let's start with the second condition. We are given

$$
u(0,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi(x)+\varphi(x)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{x}\psi(y)dy=\varphi(x)
$$

so this condition is satisfied. Next, for the third condition we apply the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\partial_{t}u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi'(x+t)-\varphi'(x-t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\psi(x+t)+\psi(x-t)\big)$$

therefore

$$\partial_{t}u(0,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(x)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\psi(x)+\psi(x)\big)=\psi(x)$$

which satisfies the third condition. To verify the first condition, we calculate three more partial derivatives

$$\partial_{t}^{2}u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi''(x+t)+\varphi''(x-t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\psi'(x+t)-\psi'(x-t)\big)$$
$$\partial_{x}u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi'(x+t)+\varphi'(x-t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\psi(x+t)-\psi(x-t)\big)$$
$$\partial_{x}^{2}u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\varphi''(x+t)+\varphi''(x-t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\psi'(x+t)-\psi'(x-t)\big)$$

from which we see that

$$\partial_{t}^{2}u(t,x)-\partial_{x}^{2}u(t,x)=0$$

as required.